# Can the conditions of a plea bargain deal be made public in the United States?

Tags: united-states, plea

Can the conditions of a plea bargain deal be made public in the United States?

https://www.theglobeandmail.com/politics/article-huaweis-meng-to-resolve-fraud-case-in-plea-deal-that-does-not-include/

> The U.S. plea deal contains no mention of Canadians Michael Spavor and
> Michael Kovrig, whom China locked up in December, 2018, in apparent
> retaliation for the arrest of Ms. Meng, a member of China’s corporate
> elite. The Canadian government has been kept abreast of the U.S. legal
> negotiations with Ms. Meng, but officials would not say whether there
> is a side agreement between Washington and Beijing that would free the
> two men, whom Canada has said are victims of hostage diplomacy.
>
> Ms. Meng appeared by teleconference on Friday before a U.S. federal
> court in Brooklyn, where a judge approved the legal arrangement
> between the United States and the Huawei executive. In the deal, she
> accepted a significant portion of the U.S. government’s case against
> her, including an attempt to evade U.S. sanctions against Iran. But
> she did not have to pay a fine or enter a guilty plea as part of the
> arrangement, in which the charges will be deferred and then dismissed
> on Dec. 1, 2022.

It is mentioned that she didn't have to enter a guilty plea as part of the arrangement, so I was curious as to what kind of deal she made. Can this be made public at the request of the public, or will it remain unknown indefinitely since the laws doesn't allow the public to request such an information in the U.S.?

Comment: plenty of detail here https://www.justice.gov/opa/pr/huawei-cfo-wanzhou-meng-admits-misleading-global-financial-institution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a deferred prosecution. The conditions of a plea agreement are generally made public, I don't know if that would apply to a deferred prosecution.